# Get list of common dictionaries from List of dictionaries on one key value match

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, merge

I am trying to merge the list of dictionaries inside a list based on a value of key "host". The sample input for the same looks like:

```
first = [{'host': '1', 'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, {'host': '2', 'a': 'c', 'd': 'd'}, {'host': '3', 'a': 'd', 'd': 'd'}]

second = [{'host': '1', 'a': 'w', 'b': 'e'}, {'host': '2', 'a': 'q', 'd': 's'}, {'host': '3', 'a': 'q', 'd': 'c'}]

third= [{'host': '1', 'a': 'r', 'b': 't'}, {'host': '2', 'a': 'f', 'd': 'b'}, {'host': '3', 'a': 'k', 'd': 'p'}]
```

I am trying to get output like this

```
final_list = {
  "1": [
    { "host": "1", "a": "a", "b": "b" },
    { "host": "1", "a": "w", "b": "e" },
    { "host": "1", "a": "r", "b": "t" }
  ],
  "2": [
    { "host": "2", "a": "c", "d": "d" },
    { "host": "2", "a": "q", "d": "s" },
    { "host": "2", "a": "f", "d": "b" }
  ],
  "3": [
    { "host": "3", "a": "d", "d": "d" },
    { "host": "3", "a": "q", "d": "c" },
    { "host": "3", "a": "k", "d": "p" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to zip them pairwise and then use enumerate to annotate the pairs starting at 1.

```
final_list = {str(num): [a, b, c] for num, (a, b, c) in 
              enumerate(zip(first, second, third), start = 1)}

>>> final_list

{'1': [{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'host': '1'},
       {'a': 'w', 'b': 'e', 'host': '1'},
       {'a': 'r', 'b': 't', 'host': '1'}],
 '2': [{'a': 'c', 'd': 'd', 'host': '2'},
       {'a': 'q', 'd': 's', 'host': '2'},
       {'a': 'f', 'd': 'b', 'host': '2'}],
 '3': [{'a': 'd', 'd': 'd', 'host': '3'},
       {'a': 'q', 'd': 'c', 'host': '3'},
       {'a': 'k', 'd': 'p', 'host': '3'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gathered your List for simpler use  and you can do that:

```py
first = [{'host': '1', 'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, {'host': '2', 'a': 'c', 'd': 'd'}, {'host': '3', 'a': 'd', 'd': 'd'}]

second = [{'host': '1', 'a': 'w', 'b': 'e'}, {'host': '2', 'a': 'q', 'd': 's'}, {'host': '3', 'a': 'q', 'd': 'c'}]

third= [{'host': '1', 'a': 'r', 'b': 't'}, {'host': '2', 'a': 'f', 'd': 'b'}, {'host': '3', 'a': 'k', 'd': 'p'}]

final_dict = {}

allList = [first, second, third]

for aList in allList:
  for aDict in aList:
    if aDict["host"] not in final_dict.keys():
      final_dict[aDict["host"]] = [aDict]
    else:
      final_dict[aDict["host"]].append([aDict])

print(final_dict)
```